# Cannot Initialize Page Factory in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I face an Issue to Initialize elements

```
static HomePageFactory HomePageFactory = new HomePageFactory();
PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.Instance, HomePageFactory);
```

and the throw the below exception

> Result Message: Test method Form4_Tests.LoginTests.FirstLogin threw exception: System.ArgumentNullException: page cannot be null Parameter name: page Result StackTrace:
>   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory.InitElements(Object page, IElementLocator locator, IPageObjectMemberDecorator decorator) at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects.PageFactory.InitElements(ISearchContext driver, Object page) at Form4_Framework.HomePage.IsExist() in d:\Test Automation\Form4_Framework\Form4_Framework\HomePage.cs:line 20 at Form4_Tests.LoginTests.FirstLogin() in d:\Test Automation\Form4_Framework\Form4_Tests\LoginTests.cs:line 46

1- Where should I initialize page factory (test method , test initialize or class initialize)? and
2- what if some elements are hidden in page, Can i initialize specific elements?

Answer (score 0):

Two things  :

1. I doubt you have typed in something incorrect, please copy and paste the entire content properly :

   ```
   static HomePageFactory HomePageFactory = new HomePageFactory(); //objects name shall not be same as the class
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.Instance, HomePageFactory);
   ```

   To

   ```
   PageFactory.InitElements(Driver.Instance, HomePageFactory.class);
   ```

***Note*** : You can use Page Factory at class level.

Comment: it's working now successfully, now i have an issue to initialize list of elements

Comment: @AhmedBahgat : you've got to ask that in a separate thread then :)